# HTML5 ui-controls pick up from canvas-1 and drag-and-drop onto cnvas-2

Tags: drag-and-drop, html5-canvas, uicontrolevents

I am very new to web based programming and have started with HTML5 from this week.
I have create a bunch of flow-chart diagrams on first canvas-1 programmatically by javascript and by using addflow (Lassange) HTML5 controls. Now I have another canvas-2 at its side on which I want the user to pick any given UI-control (from canvas-1) and drag-and-drop the same on canvas-2. BUT I am unable to achieve this.

I tried assigning draggable property to the programmatically created ui-control (canvas-1) and also made the canvas-1 draggable etc but I think this approach will not work. The UI-control does get dragged but ONLY within the boundaries of canvas-1. Now how do I ensure that an user can be able to do this... what should be my javascript coding approach at the html-page-behind?.

EDIT: Somebody who is acquainted with Lassalle's technologies -- 'AddFlow' HTML5 jscript component can be of more help here because I am using that HTML5 control to create two canvas and for filling the set of UI-controls as a 'pallet' into the canvas-1. But if somebody has achieved this through some native HTML5 javascripting or alike then still do reply.